# How to tune the scalability of play framework app?

Tags: playframework, scalability, playframework-2.1

I am using Play framework 2.1 to develop my app. It is quite easy-to-use framework. I am able to develop my app quickly. But I also ran into some scalability issues. It seems the Play 2.1 doesn't run as fast as claimed. Maybe that is because I didn't know to tune the performance.

My problem is following: I have an API to login a user with his/her email.

I used Apache Benchmark (ab) to use the performance. One single request takes about 230ms. When there are 5 concurrent requests, the response time is still fast enough, about 280ms.

```
Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   0.306 seconds
Complete requests:      5
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      3495 bytes
Total POSTed:           1065
HTML transferred:       3135 bytes
Requests per second:    16.34 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       306.009 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       61.202 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          11.15 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        3.40 kb/s sent
                        14.55 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    1   0.1      1       1
Processing:   280  290  13.8    292     305
Waiting:      278  288  13.7    291     304
Total:        280  291  13.9    293     306
```

However, when I used 100 concurrent requests, I got very bad results.

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.243 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      69900 bytes
Total POSTed:           21300
HTML transferred:       62700 bytes
Requests per second:    23.57 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4243.058 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       42.431 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          16.09 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        4.90 kb/s sent
                        20.99 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1   62  31.5     83      89
Processing:   996 3744 544.7   3902    4146
Waiting:      995 3727 542.0   3894    4146
Total:       1084 3806 542.6   3968    4204
```

My server machine: Intel i7, 8 cores, 2.8GHz, 8GB memory. I used default setting of play framework. Anyone knows how to tune the performances of play framework?

I think it relates to thread pool size. The document says play's default thread pool size is # cores. In that case, the expected time to handle all 100 requests is:

```
230ms * (100 / 8) = 2875ms
```

So, should I increase the size of default thread pool? But the document says I should get the best performance when pool size is equal to # cores.

Also, will netty's (play's web server) thread pool size affect the performance? I didn't find any information about its default value. Anyone knows how it is configured?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems your question is targeting scalability instead of performance. Regarding performance, IMHO 230ms/req is also not that fast, so I'd also check what's the reason for this. Do you have any clue what's taking most of the time, e.g. backend calls, app specific computation or template rendering?

Comment: Make sure you are benchmarking against Play in PROD mode by running `play start`.  DEV mode has a ton of overhead for auto-reload.

Answer (score 7):

Play's default threads configuration is designed for applications that use asynchronous APIs.

If you make a lot of blocking calls (typically, "standard" JDBC database calls), you will need to adjust the default ThreadPool, or execute your DB calls in another specifically configured ThreadPool.

To understand all these mechanisms, I can suggest you to read the [Thread Pools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ThreadPools) section of the Play Framework documentation. It contains very useful informations on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx32000m for example runs your JVM with 32gb of heap memory.

-Xmx256m is around the default for debugging mode so you can change it to match how much you want it to expand within your server's RAM memory space. Depending on your machine's I/O rate, garbage collection cycles can seem like pauses if there is a lot to clean but is generally ~20ms and not noticeable depending on the app's purpose.